# OpenCV issue : FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and Python but managed to install these using online tutorials. I am trying to run the following script :

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import face_utils
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import dlib
import cv2
import subprocess
def sound_alarm(path):
# play an alarm sound
subprocess.call(["afplay",path])

def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):
A = dist.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
B = dist.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])
C = dist.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])
ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)
return ear

   ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
   help="path to facial landmark predictor")
   ap.add_argument("-a", "--alarm", type=str, default="",
    help="path alarm .WAV file")
   ap.add_argument("-w", "--webcam", type=int, default=0,
    help="index of webcam on system")
   args = vars(ap.parse_args())

   EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.25
   EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES = 10
   COUNTER = 0
   ALARM_ON = False

   print("[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...")
   detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
   predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args["shape_predictor"])

(lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]

print("[INFO] starting video stream thread...")
vs = VideoStream(src=args["webcam"]).start()
time.sleep(1.0)

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rects = detector(gray, 0)
    for rect in rects:
        shape = predictor(gray, rect)
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)
        leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
        rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
        leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
        rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)
        ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0
        leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
        rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
            COUNTER += 1
            if COUNTER >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:
                if not ALARM_ON:
                    ALARM_ON = True
                    if args["alarm"] != "":
                        t = Thread(target=sound_alarm,
                            args=(args["alarm"],))
                        t.deamon = True
                        t.start()
                cv2.putText(frame, "DROWSINESS ALERT!", (10, 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        else:
            COUNTER = 0
            ALARM_ON = False
        cv2.putText(frame, "EAR: {:.2f}".format(ear), (300, 30),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

The script runs fine but I get the following issues :

1) There is no alarm sound as per the trigger condition (alarm.wav).

2) On executing this script :

```
python detect_drowsiness.py --shape-predictor 
shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat --alarm alarm.wav
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mandeesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Mandeesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-
32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "detect_drowsiness.py", line 18, in sound_alarm
    subprocess.call(["afplay",path])
   File "C:\Users\Mandeesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\subprocess.py", line 317, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Mandeesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Mandeesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
   32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am totally new to opencv and python and tried this script for a friend's project. Can anyone help in suggesting the potential issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

The error is occurring because your script is not passing in the correct filepath to the `sound_alarm(path)` function.

Check your lines containing:

```
                    if args["alarm"] != "":
                    t = Thread(target=sound_alarm,
                        args=(args["alarm"],))
                    t.deamon = True
                    t.start()
```

If you are having trouble with getting the `sound_alarm(path)` to work, I recommend isolating the issue first with a simple function in a separate script to test out if your alarm plays.

You can try:

```
import subprocess
path = r'C:\your_file_path_here'
def sound_alarm(path):
    # play an alarm sound
    print ('entered function')
    subprocess.call(["afplay",path])
    print ('ended function')
sound_alarm(path)
```

If you get `entered function` and `ended function` printed in your console line, and there is still no sound played, that means the `subprocess.call` has issues with how the sound is being played by the file, meaning the code calling the file is wrong and has to be reworked or the file has issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks figured out the issue. I was trying to run a MACOS function 'afplay' on Windows. Modified the script using 'playsound' and the sound triggers as it should!

Thank you.